# Maintain aspect ratio and font size based on browser height and width?

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

The code below is attached to `window.onresize = resize;`. The `baseWidth` and `baseHeight` are read on load as a basis for the calculations. The `main` variable is defined just by setting it to the main html node. The font is set on a block element to cause all of the `em` based elements within it to resize in kind. When the width or height of the browser is changed then the ratio is recalculated. Please see demo to understand what I achieve with JS but would like to find a pure CSS solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nLauF

I have been exploring options in CSS3 such as `calc`. Feel free to also suggest any improvements to the JS below also.

```
             function resize() {
                var height = 0,
                    width = 0;

                if(window.innerWidth <= window.innerHeight) {
                    size = window.innerWidth / baseWidth;
                    height = baseHeight * size;
                    width = window.innerWidth;

                } else {
                    size = window.innerHeight / baseHeight;
                    height = window.innerHeight;
                    width = baseWidth * size;
                }

                if(baseWidth * size > window.innerWidth) {
                    size = window.innerWidth / baseWidth;
                    height = baseHeight * size;
                    width = window.innerWidth;
                }

                main.style.height = height + "px";
                main.style.width = width + "px";
                main.style.fontSize = size * 16 + "px";
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Height equal to dynamic width (CSS fluid layout)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout)

Comment: also this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div/23673392 and this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css

Comment: @web-tiki this is the one that is closest if not spot on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css Thanks!

Comment: @web-tiki there is one thing missing. The font-size recalculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this code including font-size calculation with [vmin units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/890e1194/)**

*CSS :*

```
main {
    width: 80vmin;
    height: 60vmin;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    left:0; right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px; /* general fallback */
    font-size: 5vm; /* IE9 fallback */
    font-size: 5vmin;
}
```

For browser support, you can check [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: This is closer. The `font-size` resizing only works for the width and not the height. There is a bug that is know for this. The height or width must be 100% of one or the other, whichever is less. The reason that is because it would then allow it to be used in a body tag or nested as a child.

Bug for vw on height: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124331

Said to be fixed but still is broken in Chrome as well as in other browsers: http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: @ClearBucket just remembered `vmin` units, it can also be applied to font-size, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/890e1194/

Answer (score 0):

I adapted a piece of CSS i wrote for a different project to solve your problem: [**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/5qf5qhwp/)
I achieved the aspect ration of 4-3 by using a .75 multiplier (i.e. the width of main is 50% and the height should be 75% of that so the padding-top is 37.5%). You can see how these are adjustable to lock in your ratio.

```
.main {
  width: 50% !important;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 37.5% 0 0 0;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.main-inner {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
.main-inner-relative {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
}
p { 
  color: white; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This would require you to modify your HTML like so:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-inner">
        <div class="main-inner-relative">
            <p>hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413711/floated-columns-not-aligning-correctly-on-certain-screen-sizes) -- this reference is my original solution used to keep images locked into an aspect ratio responsively

[reference 2](http://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design/)

Comment: Yours does not work with height. This has a fiddle in it that is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css Thanks for your answer! @web-tiki got this one for finding what I was looking for.