# How to prevent a Cordova application built with Monaca from using default system font-size?

Tags: android, cordova, fonts, onsen-ui, monaca

I am working on small cordova mobile application ,so i have been using Monaca and Onsen UI because they are very useful and helpful for such things

The problem i got that when i run the app in my phone i get very small fonts because i am using tiny fonts in my phone but when i set it to medium or small they app looks well

The question is :how can i prevent my app from using the default system font-size
I even added the Mobile Accessibility plugin but it seems that Monaca does not support it yet

Comment: Monaca supports all Cordova / Phonegap plugins.  You have to have a paid developers account to include them in your project.  Fonts, in a hybrid applications, are controlled by CSS.  Assign a class to your text and control it that way.

Comment: Thanks @Munsterlander I know that but i am still beginner and i cant pay for those services yet , and i know well that i can control everything using css but there's problem each time i change the font style for example if i set a text to 50px it will not look the same in an other device (same screen but different resolution)

Comment: Check out this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768602/maintain-aspect-ratio-and-font-size-based-on-browser-height-and-width

Comment: Sorry that didn't work the font size keep changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Option:**

[HERE](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility) is a library for Cordova that will allow you to ignore the user's device defaults for text scaling, screen reading and color-inversion.

You would then implement via:

```
if($window.MobileAccessibility){
        $window.MobileAccessibility.usePreferredTextZoom(false);//Dont Scale Text
    }
```

This works with `Ionic` framework, and seeing as it is a Cordova libriary it should work with `Monaca` as well.

This implementation should be used AFTER [Cordova deviceready](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) call.

**Second Option:**

While in normal Android Development, to account for this issue a Developer would use `DP` for UI Elements, however in a HTML/CSS built app we don;t have access to this.

You would instead target CSS properties:

```
vw: 1/100th viewport width
vh: 1/100th viewport height
vmin: 1/100th of the smallest side
vmax: 1/100th of the largest side
```

Drawbacks include: Doesn't work in Opera or on iOS devices properly.

Also note: The reason for this behavior is that devices and apps are meant to be weaved together according to proper UI/UX design. This meaning any user set device UI/UX settings should also be carried into any apps they use.

While true, it is common for these rules to be ignored as long as  intentional UX/UI purpose is present and the design is not solely used to look "pretty".

**Keep in mind, many other options may be available dependent on need/use**